# Em-Editor Custom TSV

Tags: emeditor

I usually deal with large standardize delimiters similar to a “xxxx”,”xxxxx” (comma separated with quotes). Instead of those characters we use the following

Text Character        ASCII Character

———————————————

Comma ————-> 20

Quote ————-> 254

NewLine ————-> 174

Multi Value ————-> 059

Nested Value ————-> 082

Currently i use a macro with RegEx to converted to Tab Format by replacing \x{00FE}\x{14}\x{00FE} with \t  Is there a method of creating a TSV definition in EE? so i can quickly switch from format to format?

I have attempted without success, changing the delimeter in the **Tools → Customise → CSV** section, but there is method of replacing quote character

I tried replacing the delimiter in two was \x{14} and \x{00FE}\x{14}\x{00FE}

http://nextcloud.eclipsephoto.net/nextcloud/index.php/s/5b8pen55LW43cPr

I have already tried but did not seem to work,

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Please enter `\xfe\x14\xfe` in the **Delimiter** text box in the **CSV** page of the **Customize** dialog box.

Alternatively, you can replace `\xfe` with a double quote, and `\x14` with a tab after you open your file. I wrote a macro for you:

```
batch_list = editor.filters;
batch_list.AddReplace("\\xfe","\\x22",eeFindReplaceCase | eeFindReplaceEscSeq,0);  // replace \xfe with a double quote
batch_list.AddReplace("\\x14","\\t",eeFindReplaceCase | eeFindReplaceEscSeq,0);  // replace \x14 with a tab
document.selection.BatchReplace(batch_list,eeReplaceAll,0);  // batch replace
editor.ExecuteCommandByID(22529); // TSV mode
editor.ExecuteCommandByID(3894);  // heading 1
```

You can run this macro after you open your data file. To do this, save this code as, for instance, `OpenDataFile.jsee`, and then select this file from **Select...** in the **Macros** menu. Finally, open your data file, and select **Run** in the **Macros** menu while your data file is active.

**Updates**

EmEditor v20.0.901 now allows any arbitrary character to be used as a quotation mark for a CSV format. Please update EmEditor to v20.0.901 (or above), select **Customize** on the **Tools** menu, select the **CSV** page, and click the **Reset** button to add the **Concordance load file (DAT)** format to the CSV format list, or you can manually add a new format to your existing list with the delimiter of `\x14` and the quotation mark of `\xfe`.

After you open a DAT file, you can click the "DAT" button in the **CSV/Sort** toolbar. To select the DAT format automatically when a file is opened, select Properties for Current Configuration on the Tools menu, select the **File** page, and set the **Concordance Load File (DAT)** (or your new CSV Format) check box in the **CSV files to Detect** list box.

If you want to remove quotation marks (or thorns) after you open a DAT file, you can click the **CSV Converter** button in the **CSV/Sort** toolbar, and click **Remove Unnecessary Quotes** button.

Comment: Yutaka, thank you for the follow up, i think that was one of the ones i tried.  the \xfe  in the beginning and end of the line still in the list as well as the ones in empty field.   also ii was not able to switch from my Custom delimiter to coma or tab.   is there any method of addressing that?  i can provide and example if it helps.  thank you again.

Comment: on the double post on Stack, i was unable to to reply to the thread via for forum. Posted  about 4 or 5 times without success.

Comment: Please post a small sample using `code` tag here, or post a screenshot to explain your question. Let's focus on one question at a time; you can post another question regarding switch from one format to another. I understand and apologize about the forum.

Comment: [link]http://nextcloud.eclipsephoto.net/nextcloud/index.php/s/EgbxX6SMmgmjckA

Comment: @Tutaka the link above contains a sample of  data. It is standard  in the field of Ediscovery.   ideally the file should be associates with EE and load automatically in Tab delimited format with the top row fixed in position.      More information is located here [link]http://help.ediscoveryplatform.com/tiff-image-dat-load-file#:~:text=A%20standardized%20TIFF%20Concordance%20load,line%2C%20and%20includes%20document%20metadata. on the bottom of the page "Concordance Load File Format"

Comment: I saw your sample data. If you want to open TSV (Tab-separated) files automatically (assuming you already converted `\xfe\x14\xfe` with a tab), go to **Configuration Properties** > **File**, and then set the **Tab separated** option. To fix the first row, go to **Customize** dialog > **CSV** > your format > select `1` from **Lines of Headings**. Also, you can go to **Tools** menu > **Associate Configuration** > click **Associate with EmEditor** to associate your file type with EmEditor.

Comment: I was hoping to have these file files open automatically in tab format  without  converting the delimiters manually. and place a tab in the menu  to be able to covert from one format to another. Almost always, these files need to be converted back. .I currently use a macro for this, and to removed the first and last dosimeter of the line.   but sometimes  i have issues with the conversion.  thank you for the assistance. At a  minimum,  you help me find the location of where to make the first line fixed. I looked for so long.

Comment: Would it be helpful if EmEditor could customize the double quote character to \xFE so that you can open your data file without any replacements? I also wrote a macro for you, and updated my answer.

Comment: I was about to suggest the same. Instead if hard coding the quote  in **Allow delimiter in Double quotes** located in the **customize**  section (i think that is what is used) if that is made, to be replaceable, should do the trick.   Also this is  standard across legal industry  database and i am sure most of my colleagues  would benefit form using an application that allow these files to be manipulated easily.

Comment: The next version will include an ability to change the quotation mark for each CSV format. It will also add the Concordance load file (DAT) format to the default CSV list. Thanks for your inputs!

Comment: I've just released v20.0.901, where you can click the Reset button in the CSV page of the Customize dialog box to add the Concordance load file (DAT) format to the CSV format list, or you can add a new format manually to your existing list. I will update my answer.

Comment: Yutkam - Just saw the update - did not get notification on new entries. Excellent! Is there an option to remove the "þ" symbol from view?  Currently they remain as part of the data   ![Concordance Dat](http://nextcloud.eclipsephoto.net/nextcloud/index.php/s/TEXFYn7iTK2YGWM)    I am still experimenting with this. Will the file save in the same format?

Comment: Do you actually want to remove "þ" symbols (quotation marks) from the file, or do you just want to hide these symbols from view? If you actually want to remove quotation marks, you can use the **Remove Unnecessary Quotes** command. To do this, you can click the **CSV Converter** in the **CSV/Sort** toolbar, and then click the **Remove Unnecessary Quotes** button. Alternatively, press `Ctrl + Q` to show the **Quick Launch** window, and search for `Remove Unnecessary Quotes`.  You can't just hide quotation marks.

Comment: I got mixed result with “remove unnecessary Quotes” It worked on a small file and had no effect on others.  However, that is exactly what is needed, these files are often modified by reducing the number of rows and columns and re-saved in the original format. Having the quote character along with the data distracts the user.  I noticed the quotes were not saved during a save-as when removed. Ideally, the file should open without the quotes and inserted during the save/save-as option.

Comment: Additionally, one should be able to switch between comma, Tab, Semicolon and now DAT options on the toolbar to save the file in different format (for other systems and databases).  So is a open a DAT file and then switch to semicolon or TAB it should be saved with should be saved with the semicolon or TAB and vice-versa. I am including a sample DAT file just incase. ![SampleDat]( http://nextcloud.eclipsephoto.net/nextcloud/index.php/s/rEaB5NYrTqTQZed)

Comment: I reproduced the issue. After you open a large file, deselect the **Use Temporary Files** option and click **Apply** button in the **Large File Controller**. After you switch to a CSV format, select the 2nd or below row first, and then select the **Remove Unnecessary Quotes** command. I will fix this issue on the next version.